# Setting automake install filename to be different from original filename

Tags: automake

Is it possible to setup automake to install a file under a different name? For instance, let's say I have a LICENSE file in my package, which I want to be installed under /usr/share/licenses/mypackage. Is it possible to extend the code below, so that the LICENSE file is installed as "mypackage"?

```
licensedir = $(datadir)/licenses
license_DATA = LICENSE
```

I've been googling on this for quite some time now, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to add an install hook:

```
install-data-hook:
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/licenses; \
    mv LICENSE mypackage
```

Comment: Does this work inside an AUTOmake file? If I add your code to my Makefile.am, I get "No rule to make target `LICENSE', needed by `all-am'." at the end of make.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to cd to the target dir. Yes, this is for Automake - the rule install-data-local only means something special to Automake.

Comment: The hook would be `install-data-hook` and is executed after all other `install-data` rules. `install-data-local` may be executed before `install-license_DATA` and then the `mv` would not work (as was my case).

Comment: I changed the target to `hook` as noted by @xOneca to remove a race condition I experienced and also `$(DESTDIR)` prefix is needed as well.